# Session not getting associated with the username PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I don't understand why I'm not able to associate the username who logged in with a session. 
I will be really thankful if you can guys can help me out here?

Here's the example code:

```
session_start();

include 'includes/connect.php';

if (isset($_POST['user'], $_POST['pass'])) {
    //assigning parameters to variables.
    $user = $_POST['user'];
    $pass = $_POST['pass'];

    $sql = 'SELECT id FROM users WHERE username=(:user) AND password=(:pass)';

    try {
        $connect = new PDO("mysql:host=$host; dbname=$dbname;", $username, $password);
        $connect->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
        $values = $connect->prepare($sql);
        $values->bindParam('user', $user, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $values->bindParam('pass', $pass, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $values->execute();
        $row_count = $values->rowCount();
        $row = $values->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

        ////////////////////////////
        //user and pass section [DB]
        //$usr_db = $row['username'];
        //$pwd_db = $row['password'];
        ////////////////////////////

        if ($row_count === 1) {
            $_SESSION['Logged_in'] = $user;
            echo 'THIS TEXT REMAINS..';
        }
    } catch (PDOException $e) {
        echo 'Error: ' . $e->getMessage();
    }
}
```

Comment: You are not using the session information anymore, you just set the session variable "Logged_in" to the username.
If you want to get the user name again you have to do something like `$user = $_SESSION["Logged_in"]`

Comment: I did this for a test : `<?php 
session_start();

$user = $_GET["name"];


if ($user == "admin") {
 $_SESSION["user_login"] = $user;
}

if (isset($_SESSION["user_login"])) {
 echo "DONE!";
}
?>` here once you do ?name=admin the word DONE! stays on the page until i delete the session. i want same in that case.

Comment: @KlausGF. The problem i am getting is the session doesn't remains. i don't know why. I tried but the text doesn't remains on the page. -
`if (isset($_SESSION["Logged_in"])) {
   echo "THIS TEXT REMAINS!";
  }
`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've not really given us enough information to help you yet but I'm going to make an educated guess. You want the text "THIS TEXT REMAINS.." to appear all the time. Why this won't happen is because execution will never reach that point unless the username and password are posted on every request, which I assume is not what happens. If you reorganize your code like this you might get the result you expect.

```
session_start();

include 'includes/connect.php';

if (isset($_POST['user'], $_POST['pass'])) {
    //assigning parameters to variables.
    $user = $_POST['user'];
    $pass = $_POST['pass'];

    $sql = 'SELECT id FROM users WHERE username=(:user) AND password=(:pass)';

    try {
        $connect = new PDO("mysql:host=$host; dbname=$dbname;", $username, $password);
        $connect->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
        $values = $connect->prepare($sql);
        $values->bindParam('user', $user, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $values->bindParam('pass', $pass, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $values->execute();
        $row_count = $values->rowCount();
        $row = $values->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

        ////////////////////////////
        //user and pass section [DB]
        //$usr_db = $row['username'];
        //$pwd_db = $row['password'];
        ////////////////////////////

        if ($row_count === 1) {
            $_SESSION['Logged_in'] = $user;
        }
    } catch (PDOException $e) {
        echo 'Error: ' . $e->getMessage();
    }
}

// Moved the login check down here so it's executed on every request.
if (array_key_exists('Logged_in', $_SESSION) && $_SESSION['Logged_in'] !== null) {
    echo 'THIS TEXT REMAINS..';
}
```